# Why does my method return null?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my class which declares an array of Squares, for some reason, when I call the `GetGameBoardSquare()` method (in another class), it returns null.

Is there a problem with my `GetGameBoardSquare()` method? or maybe a problem with the way I have declared the squares?

```
public static class Board 
{
    private static Square[] gameBoard = new Square[56];

    static public void SetUpBoard()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i == 55; i++)
        {
            gameBoard[i] = new Square("Ordinary Square", i);       
        }

        gameBoard[0] = new Square("Start", 0);
        gameBoard[4] = new Square.Lose_Square("Lose Square", 4);
        gameBoard[5] = new Square.Chance_Square("Chance Square", 5);
        gameBoard[9] = new Square.Win_Square("Win Square", 9);         
        gameBoard[11] = new Square.Chance_Square("Chance Square", 11);
        gameBoard[14] = new Square.Lose_Square("Lose Square", 14);   
        gameBoard[17] = new Square.Chance_Square("Chance Square", 17);      
        gameBoard[19] = new Square.Win_Square("Win Square", 19); 
        gameBoard[24] = new Square.Lose_Square("Lose Square", 24);
        gameBoard[29] = new Square.Win_Square("Win Square", 29);
        gameBoard[34] = new Square.Lose_Square("Lose Square", 34);
        gameBoard[35] = new Square.Chance_Square("Chance Square", 35);
        gameBoard[39] = new Square.Win_Square("Win Square", 39);
        gameBoard[44] = new Square.Lose_Square("Lose Square", 44);
        gameBoard[47] = new Square.Chance_Square("Chance Square", 47);       
        gameBoard[49] = new Square.Win_Square("Win Square", 49);
        gameBoard[53] = new Square.Chance_Square("Chance Square", 53);   
        gameBoard[55] = new Square("Finish", 56);
    }

    public static Square GetGameBoardSquare(int n)
    {
        Square S = new Square();
        S = gameBoard[n];

        return S;
    }

    public static Square StartSquare()
    {
        return gameBoard[0];
    }

    public static Square NextSquare(int n)
    {

        return gameBoard[(n+1)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Your `For` loop is not right. It never loops in your codes. make it like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 55; i++)
{
   //your code
}
```

Comment: @user2396303 Please consider checking the answer as the right answer if it was helpful to encourage more pepole to answer your questions

Comment: wierd thing happened, my program worked the first time did what it was meant to do, then the second time, it didn't, after changing nothing! idk whats happened now

Comment: @user2396303 What do you mean by *not working*? are you getting `null` returns again?

Comment: Yeah, System.NullReferenceException error, at a place where there was no error..

Comment: @user2396303 Then consider asking new question about the new problem, or explain more here

Comment: the part that draws an error is ` float textWidth = textFont.Size * name.Length;` it is in another class but did not draw an error before, any clue?

Comment: @user2396303 It is somthing that you should explain more by showing more codes. I suggest asking a new question

Comment: God damn it i would give anything to go back to the working solution i just had!

Comment: I cant ask another question for 90minutes so..

Comment: @user2396303 I'd advise you to spend some time yourself debugging the issue. Clearly `textFont` or `name` (or both) are null, so you should examine with a debugger how they get to be null. Asking SO for every minor issue will not help you gain an understanding of how programming works. Google for 'null reference exception' and you'll find a *very* detailed guide about how and why this error occurs.

Comment: @Rob I'd go with your advise. `Asking SO for every minor issue will not help you gain an understanding of how programming works` very nice said.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning that in addition to the obvious `for` loop bug, the whole class is very error prone.
First, it cannot operate correctly if `SetUpBoard` is not called. Since it looks like this is a static immutable information, it would be much better to make the private array readonly and fully initialize it with either initializer or inside a static constructor.
Second, inside that setup, it's very hard to see what's going on. And also if you mess up something. For instance, looks like the second argument of the `Square` classes constructor is the index, but not in this line `gameBoard[55] = new Square("Finish", 56);` It might be intentional, but more likely is a bug.

Here is an example that avoids all those pitfalls:

```
public static class Board 
{
    const int N = 56;

    private static readonly Square[] gameBoard = 
        Enumerable.Range(0, N).Select(n => CreateSquare(n)).ToArray();

    static Square CreateSquare(int n)
    {
        switch (n)
        {
            case 0:
                return new Square("Start", n);
            case N - 1:
                return new Square("Finish", n);
            case 4:
            case 14:
            case 24:
            case 34:
            case 44:
                return new Square.Lose_Square("Lose Square", n);
            case 5:
            case 17:
            case 35:
            case 47:
                return new Square.Chance_Square("Chance Square", n);
            case 9:
            case 19:
            case 29:
            case 39:
            case 49:
                return new Square.Win_Square("Win Square", n);
            default:
                return new Square("Ordinary Square", n);
        }
    }

    public static Square GetGameBoardSquare(int n)
    {
        return gameBoard[n];
    }

    public static Square StartSquare()
    {
        return gameBoard[0];
    }

    public static Square NextSquare(int n)
    {
        return gameBoard[n + 1];
    }
}
```

Of course there are many other ways to do that, but the `switch` statement allows you easily rearrange what goes where, keeps you from using duplicate indices and is readable.